# Conditionally to choose which classes to inherit

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

So, I've got a diamond hierarchy.

```cpp
class Base {
    // ...
}
    
class Derived_A : public Base {
    // ...
}
    
class Derived_B : public Base {
    // ...
}
    
class Join : public Derived_A, public Derived_B {
    // ...
}
```

Depending on a template variable, I would like to conditionally choose to inherit A and/or B. (I understand with the diamond structure, A and B can be virtually inherited.) What I have exactly is:

```cpp
template<bool HAS_A, bool HAS_B>
class Join : public Derived_A, // enable if HAS_A
             public Derived_B  // enable if HAS_B
{
    // ...
}
```

I attempted to use `std::enable_if_t`, but I am not sure that will work when the boolean to it is `false`.

Comment: When both `HAS_A` and `HAS_B` are `false`, `Join` should inherit nothing?

Comment: In my case, one will ALWAYS be `true`, but both could be `true` as well. Both cannot be `false`. But I'll be curious to learn about the case where it inherits nothing.

Comment: `struct empty{}; class Join : std::conditional_t<HAS_A, Derived_A, empty>` repeat for B.

Comment: Specifying the base class instead of using `bool` as template parameter seems more straightforward. e.g. `template<class... Base> class Join : public Base... {};`, then use it like `Join<Derived_A, Derived_B>`, `Join<Derived_A>`, `Join<Derived_B>`, `Join<>`.

Comment: Thank you, both of these suggestions work. I am gonna try @songyuanyao's, seems exactly what I need and I don't have to manage booleans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specifying the base classes instead of using `bool` as template parameter seems more straightforward. e.g.

```
template<class... Base> class Join : public Base... {};
```

then use it like `Join<Derived_A, Derived_B>`, `Join<Derived_A>`, `Join<Derived_B>`, and `Join<>` (inherit nothing).